# Print extended ascii with write function

Tags: c

How do I print character 128 from extended ascii with write function in c language?

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    c = 128;
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:�

Ascii extended 128: Ç

Comment: use a terminal that handle it.

Comment: Such code is sensitive to endianness.

Comment: Is the question how to print `(unsigned char)128` or how to print `Ç`?  They are not necessarily the same.  When they differ, what is the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the Unicode version

```
uint16_t x = 0x87C3; // little endian (beware endianness matters)
write(1, &x, 2);
```

(a type that has 2 bytes)

To remove any endianness issue, use an array instead

```
uint8_t y[] = { 0xC3, 0x87 };
write(1, y, 2);
```

Comment: so prints correctly, but how does it convert integer into unicode?

Comment: `2` alternative:  `sizeof x`. Better, use `uint16_t`.

Comment: @Chris there is no "conversion", Unicode *is* integer(s). Using `write` to a support that understands (or is set to) Unicode should be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `wchar_t`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t c;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    for (c = 128; c < 256; c++) {
        wprintf(L"%lc\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but only use unistd library and write function can not possible?

Comment: As written, that code generated `?` for the first 32 extended ASCII characters. Passing the different argument `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-US");` was the same, but `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-UK");` (where I am) was better. +1 for the lesson.

Comment: OP's goal is "Print ... with write function" and code sample uses `write()`.  This answer's `wprintf()` does not fulfill that.